# How can i query the chosen shipping rate of a given order using Rules in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: rules, commerce

In the checkout process, I need to add the subtotal of an order (which I have access to) with the customer-chosen shipping service amount. I can't seem to access the shipping service amount that was selected by the user. How can I access this?